# 6j-symbol from summing Clebsch-Gordan coefficients

Tags: quantum-mechanics, angular-momentum, group-theory, representation-theory

I'm trying to do some three body calculations using a harmonic oscillator basis in two relative coordinates. As part of the calculations, I get a sum of a product of multiple Clebsch-Gordan coefficients. The sum is
$$
\sum_{m_\rho' m_\lambda'} C^{L' M'}_{l_\rho' m_\rho' l_\lambda' m_\lambda'}
\sum_{m_\rho m_\lambda} C^{L M}_{l_\rho m_\rho l_\lambda m_\lambda}
\sum_{K}(2K+1)^{-3/2}C^{K0}_{l_\rho' 0l_\rho 0}C^{K N}_{l_\rho'-m_\rho'l_\rho m_\rho}
C^{K0}_{l_\lambda' 0l_\lambda 0}C^{K -N}_{l_\lambda'-m_\lambda'l_\lambda m_\lambda}
$$
where $M$ and $M'$ are fixed.

Through some algebra, I managed to get the sum to look like

$$\begin{multline}
(-1)^{M-l_\rho+l_\lambda}\left[(2l_\rho+1)(2l_\lambda'+1)\right]^{-\frac{1}{2}}\sum_{K}(-1)^K
(2K+1)^{-\frac{1}{2}}C^{K0}_{l_\rho' 0l_\rho 0} C^{K0}_{l_\lambda' 0l_\lambda 0}
\\\sum_{m_\rho'm_\lambda'm_\rho m_\lambda}(-1)^{N}
C^{L M}_{l_\rho m_\rho l_\lambda m_\lambda}
C^{l_\rho m_\rho}_{l_\rho'm_\rho'KN}
C^{L' M'}_{l_\rho' m_\rho' l_\lambda' m_\lambda'}
C^{l_\lambda'm_\lambda'}_{KNl_\lambda m_\lambda}
\end{multline}$$

That four term sum at the end looks tantalizingly close to the definition of the Wigner 6j-symbol
$$
\sum_{m_{12} m_{23} m_1 m_2 m_3}
C^{jm}_{j_{12}m_{12}j_3m_3}
C^{j_{12}m_{12}}_{j_1m_1j_2m_2}
C^{j'm'}_{j_1m_1j_{23}m_{23}}
C^{j_{23}m_{23}}_{j_2m_2j_3m_3}\\
=\delta_{jj'}\delta_{mm'}(-1)^{j_1+j_2+j_3+j}\sqrt{(2j_{12}+1)(2j_{23}+1)}
\begin{Bmatrix}
j_1 & j_2 & j_{12}\\
j_3 & j & j_{23}
\end{Bmatrix}
$$
but has an extra factor of $(-1)^N$ in the sum.

Is there a way to get that factor $(-1)^N$ out of the sum? If it helps, $l_\rho'$, $l_\rho$, $l_\lambda'$, $l_\lambda$, $L$, and $L'$ must all be integers (and by extension, so must $K$ and all projections).

Comment: I don't see any sum over $N$.

Comment: @LucJ.Bourhis $N=m_\rho-m_\rho'$ both of which are summed over.

Comment: Are you sure of your last formula? The 6j are usually expressed as a $\sum_{m_1\cdots m_6}$ of 3j with a sign $(-1)^{\sum(j_p-m_p)}$ in front of each terms.

Comment: @LucJ.Bourhis The 6-j can also be written in terms of CG rather than 3j's.

Comment: At this point my guess is that there might be a small error in the algebra, but it will take a while to track down. Maybe the OP can add some context and additional details in (the likely) case this calculation exists amd can be found somewhere.

Comment: I'll get it up soon. Is there a good place to upload PDFs?

Comment: @ZeroTheHero I think I figured out what was wrong. There was no error in the algebra, the source I was using for the Wigner-D functions seems to have reversed active and passive rotations. Correcting that introduces a factor of (-1)^N, getting the sum I want.

Comment: @JohnathanGross Please do share.  I'm curious and also if you can reference the source of your source for D's with the "incorrect" convention that would be really swell.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BxCoJhQd_F_vS09wUzU4bmxOODg